# Mongodb C Driver: How to clear database?

Tags: c, mongodb

Using the Mongodb C Driver, how can I issue shell commands like db.mydb.remove()?

The API seems pretty limited: http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/api/annotated.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To drop collection use [mongo_cmd_drop_collection(…)](http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/api/mongo_8h.html#aa2199ede7418f69ee82aea0b2a446961), to drop DBs use [mongo_cmd_drop_db(…)](http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/api/mongo_8h.html#ad7780464bab6ed5b031182cb84de06c4). Most commands are inside [mongo.h](http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/api/mongo_8h.html).

Edit: To perform the requested *remove(…)* use [mongo_remove(…)](http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/api/mongo_8h.html#a6776a58fde3e24329db7be2c99d9046a).

Comment: Someone suggested an edit to my answer but strangely it is gone now. So the credits for my edit go to the anonymous editor. :)

Comment: I suggested the edit, but it was rejected by @RKN Dream Eater and strah .  I'm not quite sure what was wrong with the edit, but the canned response from them was: "This edit changes too much in the original post; the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost."  Anywho, I figured that bit should be in there as well for quick reference.

Comment: I could use  `mongo_cmd_drop_collection(…)`. But I'm not sure how to create the BSON document for the third arugment. I'm getting `expected ‘struct bson *’ but argument is of type ‘bson’`. How do I create a struct bson * type?

Comment: @resting: If you do not need the result you could use `NULL`. Otherwise something like `bson out; mongo_cmd_drop_collection(..., &out);` should do the job.

Comment: @nutlike thanks. `&out` works. but its returning a false value (-1). So i print out.errstr but it shows `(null)`. Nothing in the logs too. Or am I printing the error wrong?

Comment: @resting: I am not a C guy, but I think that all numeric values except 0 mean `TRUE`. So the drop was successful and the `errstr` is empty. Or are you sure that the drop failed?

Comment: @nutlike I'm not a C guy too. This is my first C project. I do know C doesn't have a native boolean. But usually return 0 means a successful execution, so I have this thought that 0 is `TRUE` and any others is `FALSE`. But, that aside, it did drop the collection, so you might be right. Just curious, which is your primary language?

Comment: @resting: I am coding in Java most of the time. It is indeed true that a `0` means successful execution but other numbers equate error codes, therefore the return type cannot be interpreted as an boolean value. My knowledge about *true* and *false* in *C* comes from here: http://www.le.ac.uk/users/rjm1/cotter/page_37.htm.

Comment: @nutlike I see. Java is a deep language too. Well, to clear things up, I just did a test with a non-existent collection. Pretty sure it returns `0` on success and `-1` on failure (although it doesn't explain why it failed). Not sure why I saw `-1` previously, but its returning `0` fine now. Thanks.
Adding on, according to your reference and those that I saw, C is supposed to treat `0` as false. So, I've no idea why `0` appears to be true in this case.